# This VBA function always returns an answer of 0

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a function in excel to apply a commission rate to a profit dependent on a profit margin. The profit and profit margin are both inputs to the function. However whenever I run this function, it always returns 0 despite having inputs that should return other results.

I have already looked over the code multiple times and checked that my inputs are valid but cannot find the problem. The profit margin is a fraction in the form of a percentage.

A sample of my code is shown below:

```
    'If Profit Margin is below 20% then no commission
'If Profit Margin is above 20% commission is 5%
'If Profit Margin is above 25% commission is 10%
'If Profit Margin is above 30% commission is 15%
'If Profit Margin is above 40% commission is 25%
'If Profit Margin is above 50% commission is 33%





Function CommissionPicker(ProfitMargin, Profit)


If 0.25 > ProfitMargin >= 0.2 = True Then
   CommissionPicker = 0.05 * Profit

   ElseIf 0.3 > ProfitMargin >= 0.25 = True Then
   CommissionPicker = 0.1 * Profit

   ElseIf 0.4 > ProfitMargin >= 0.3 = True Then
   CommissionPicker = 0.15 * Profit

   ElseIf 0.5 > ProfitMargin >= 0.4 = True Then
   CommissionPicker = 0.25 * Profit

   ElseIf ProfitMargin >= 0.5 = True Then
   CommissionPicker = 0.33 * Profit

   ElseIf ProfitMargin < 0.2 = True Then
   CommissionPicker = 0 * Profit

   Else
   End If


End Function
```

I expect the output to be 0 if ProfitMargin is below 20%, 0.05 x the input profit value for ProfitMargin between 20% and 25%, 0.1 x the input profit value for ProfitMargin between 25% and 30%, 0.15 x the input profit value for ProfitMargin between 30% and 40%, 0.25 x the input profit value for ProfitMargin between 40% and 50% and 0.33 x the input profit value for ProfitMargin above 50%. However the equation consistently returns a value of 0.

Comment: You can drop the `= True` on those If statements

Comment: Lines like this: `If 0.25 > ProfitMargin >= 0.2 = True Then` should be written as: `If 0.25 > ProfitMargin And ProfitMargin >= 0.2 Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot perform multiple `<` or `>` checks at once. You need to use `And`:

```
If ProfitMargin < 0.25 And ProfitMargin >= 0.2 Then
```

Additionally I recommend to specify a type for all your variables:

```
Function CommissionPicker(ByVal ProfitMargin As Double, ByVal Profit As Double) As Double
```

**Explanation**

Why does `If 0.25 > ProfitMargin >= 0.2 = True Then` fail?

Because it checks at first `0.25 > ProfitMargin` which result is `True` or `False` so the next check would be eg `True >= 0.2` or `False >= 0.2`. While `True` is `-1` and `False` is `0` this is `-1 >= 0.2` or `0 >= 0.2` which both is `False`. The last check then is `False = True`, so the `If` statement is `False`.

**Alternativley to your code I recommend something like this**

```
Function CommissionPicker(ByVal ProfitMargin As Double, ByVal Profit As Double) As Double
    Select Case ProfitMargin
        Case Is < 0.2
            CommissionPicker = 0 * Profit
        Case Is < 0.25
            CommissionPicker = 0.05 * Profit
        Case Is < 0.3
            CommissionPicker = 0.1 * Profit
        Case Is < 0.4
            CommissionPicker = 0.15 * Profit
        Case Is < 0.5
            CommissionPicker = 0.25 * Profit
        Case Else
            CommissionPicker = 0.33 * Profit
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

@PEH's answer is correct for the syntax of the `If`-statement. However, I would suggest that you reorganize your code, this would simplify the logic and make it easier to read and maintain:

```
Function CommissionPicker(ProfitMargin, Profit)

    If ProfitMargin < 0.2 Then
        CommissionPicker = 0 * Profit
    ElseIf ProfitMargin < 0.25 Then
        CommissionPicker = 0.05 * Profit
    ElseIf ProfitMargin < 0.3 Then
        CommissionPicker = 0.1 * Profit
    ElseIf ProfitMargin < 0.4 Then
        CommissionPicker = 0.15 * Profit
    ElseIf ProfitMargin < 0.5 Then
        CommissionPicker = 0.25 * Profit
    Else
        CommissionPicker = 0.33 * Profit
    End If

End Function
```