# My VBA function returns a Value error when trying to run it

Tags: excel, vba

My custom VBA function returns a #VALUE! error when one of the input functions is SUM(##:##).

Whenever I only input the first two variables, the function runs fine. However, the third variable input is a SUM function and the function throws up an error. I think it is a problem with VBA not recognising it as an array or something but I'm unsure how to tackle this issue. When writing the function into the excel sheet itself, the error does not appear.

```
Function CommissionPicker(ProfitMargin, Profit, Revenue)

If ProfitMargin < 0.2 Then
    CommissionPicker = 0 * Profit
ElseIf ProfitMargin < 0.25 Then
    CommissionPicker = 0.05 * Profit
ElseIf ProfitMargin < 0.3 Then
    CommissionPicker = 0.1 * Profit
ElseIf ProfitMargin < 0.4 Then
    CommissionPicker = 0.15 * Profit
ElseIf ProfitMargin < 0.5 Then
    CommissionPicker = 0.25 * Profit
ElseIf ProfitMargin < 0.6 Then
    CommissionPicker = 0.33 * Profit
Else
    CommissionPicker = (Profit - 0.5 * Revenue) * 0.5 + (0.5 * Revenue) * 0.33
End If

End Function
```

The expected result should be 0 x the profit if the ProfitMargin is below 0.2, 0.05 x the profit if the ProfitMargin is below 0.25, 0.1 x the profit if the ProfitMargin is below 0.3, 0.15 x the profit if the ProfitMargin is below 0.4, 0.25 x the profit if the Profit Margin is below 0.5, 0.33 x the profit if the ProfitMargin is below 0.6 and follow the following equation: (Profit - 0.5 * Revenue) * 0.5 + (0.5 * Revenue) * 0.33 if the ProfitMargin is above 60%. However the function returns a #VALUE! error.

The "Revenue" Variable is an excel SUM function.

Comment: I would declare the four variables in this function as numeric variables. They're variants now so you might as well be throwing strings at the formula

Comment: As I explained in my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57036579/3219613) I recommended to declare the variables: `Function CommissionPicker(ByVal ProfitMargin As Double, ByVal Profit As Double,  ByVal Revenue As Double) As Double`

Comment: First step of debugging code yourself is... well, debugging. Use `F8` to step through the code and see what values all variables contain. Alternatively you could use `Debug.Print Revenue` to print values to the immediate window (CTRL + G)

Comment: Hi, sorry I must have missed that bit in your original answer PEH. Unfortunately the error still remains. The error isn't in the VBA developer window but in the actual spreadsheet. Trying to debug it myself but with no luck. Sorry if I'm being a pain

Comment: Write as first line in that function `Debug.Print ProfitMargin, Profit, Revenue`. Then go into the cell where the formula is. Press F2 and then Enter. Then go into the immediate window in the VBA Editor (Ctrl + G) and tell what was printed there.

Comment: Nothing was printed in the immediate window :(

Comment: That's not possible, make sure you re-enter the formula in a cell, so it is forced to re-calculate.

Comment: Still nothing there

Comment: Please tell how you call this function. What is the formula that you used? • Please also [edit] your question and update the code to what you actually use right now.

Comment: In the cell where I need the value I type: "CommissionPicker(Profit_Margin, L24, K24) Where L24 is a subtraction formula and K24 is a SUM() function

Comment: Hopfully your formula starts with a `=`? What are the values of `Profit_Margin`, `L24` and `K24`? Is your VBA function in a module or a worksheet?

Comment: yup, starts with **=**! **Profit_Margin = 64%**, **L24 = K24 - J24 = 33000** and **K24 = SUM(J11:J23) = 11825**

Comment: What happens when you enter the following formula into a cell in the same sheet `=CommissionPicker(0.64, 33000, 11825)`?

Comment: still returns a #VALUE! error. Not sure why :(

Comment: The error doesn't appear if I type 'CommissionPicker(0.64, 33000)' or 'CommissionPicker(Profit_Margin, L24)' however

Comment: Well this means you probably have `CommissionPicker` more than once in your VBA code (probably some old module anywhere)? Are you sure you use the exact code as in the question above with **all 3 parameters** in the first line of the function? Please update the code in your question to what you have.

Comment: PEH you're a star. I didn't realise that I had another module somewhere that was titled CommissionPicker and idk how it got there. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me I really appreciate it